# in >> qstr or qstr = in.readLine()

Tags: c++, qt, console, stdin, qdebug

I want to find alternative for cin >>

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QString>

int main(){
    qDebug() << "Test start";
    QTextStream in(stdin);
    QString qstr;
    qstr = in.readLine();
    qDebug() << "Test end";
}
```

Also I tried

```
in >> qstr;
```

But nothing changed. Console:

[image]

So, I input for infinitive and "Test End" isn't coming, help me please guys!

Comment: What's the platform, I tested on Win10 + Mingw, Got `Test end` after press Enter key

Comment: Im using mac os x . Qt 5.10.1
Help, please ((